# Creating XML document using Linq to XML in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am using below mentioned code to create a XML in C# :

```
     XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16","yes"),
          new XElement("Parent",
          from childItem in childItemList
          select new XElement("Child",
                    new XElement("source",childItem.Source),
                    new XElement("target", childItem.Target)
                    )));
```

Its working fine and document is created as expected. But I want to write

```
    childItem.Source 
    childItem.Target
```

as attribute values  and I used following code for that :

```
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16","yes"),
          new XElement("Parent",
          from childItem in childItemList
          select new XElement("Child",
                  (new XAttribute("value", childItem.Source))),
              new XElement("target", 
                 (new XAttribute("value",childItem.Target)))
               )));
```

This code also works fine, but the problem is I have multi-line text in

```
    childItem.Source
    childItem.Target
```

And when same is written as Inner-Text of a node, It works fine but when this is written as value of attribute the multi-line text is being converted to single line text. I want to preserve all the white-spaces and line breaks in the XML document as it is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have line breaks (CRLF) in an attribute! The line breaks are always converted from the XElement class to a hexadecimal literal in order to be "safe". I suppose this is so in order to be HTTP (or some other net protocol) conform - for example new lines are not allowed in an URI. You can always gain your CRLF back from the hexadecimal value that you have.